# call javascript function on div with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `javascript` function i would like to call on multiple `div` with same `class` but when i call the function and `hover` over the first `div` the function is called on the other `div` with same `class`

```
function flip() {
    $('.front').css("display", "none");
    $('.back').fadeIn();
}
function flipBack() {
    $('.front').fadeIn();
    $('.back').css("display", "none");
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="subMainSlates" onmouseenter="flip(this)" onmouseleave="flipBack(this)">
                <div class="front">
                    <i class="typcn typcn-globe"></i>
                    <h3>Nigeriaeexport</h3>
                    <p>Your one stop export solution platform for everything export.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                    Want to work
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="subMainSlates" onmouseenter="flip(this)" onmouseleave="flipBack(this)">
                <div class="front">
                    <i class="typcn typcn-location-arrow"></i>
                    <h3>XPT Logistics</h3>
                    <p>The top Company in terms of Export Logistics in Nigeria</p>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                    Want to work
                </div>
            </div>
```

What I want is when `mouseenter` the `.subMainSlate` the `.front` `fadeOut()` and `.back` `fadeIn()`.

Thanks.

Comment: see the answer. You missed using find.

Comment: Yes. Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `this` as the argument to the handler, but you're not using it. All you need to do is define a parameter on your function and use that.

```
function flip(elem) {
    // 'elem' is the element that received the event
    $(elem).find('.front').css("display", "none");
    $(elem).find('.back').fadeIn();
}
function flipBack(elem) {
    // 'elem' is the element that received the event
    $(elem).find('.front').fadeIn();
    $(elem).find('.back').css("display", "none");
}
```

Comment: Works fine now.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of binding event on class , bind event on element which is whithin the root node. You can use [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) selector to select only nodes which are part of root node.

```js
function flip(el) {
    $(el).find('.front').css("display", "none");
    $(el).find('.back').fadeIn();
}
function flipBack(el) {
    $(el).find('.front').fadeIn();
    $(el).find('.back').css("display", "none");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subMainSlates" onmouseenter="flip(this)" onmouseleave="flipBack(this)">
                <div class="front">
                    <i class="typcn typcn-globe"></i>
                    <h3>Nigeriaeexport</h3>
                    <p>Your one stop export solution platform for everything export.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                    Want to work
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="subMainSlates" onmouseenter="flip(this)" onmouseleave="flipBack(this)">
                <div class="front">
                    <i class="typcn typcn-location-arrow"></i>
                    <h3>XPT Logistics</h3>
                    <p>The top Company in terms of Export Logistics in Nigeria</p>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                    Want to work
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `find()` on the targeted element like the following:

```js
function flip(that) {
  $(that).find('.fornt').css("display", "none");
  $(that).find('.back').fadeIn();
}
function flipBack(that) {
  $(that).find('.front').fadeIn();
  $(that).find('.back').css("display", "none");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subMainSlates" onmouseenter="flip(this)" onmouseleave="flipBack(this)">
    <div class="front">
        <i class="typcn typcn-globe"></i>
        <h3>Nigeriaeexport</h3>
        <p>Your one stop export solution platform for everything export.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        Want to work
    </div>
</div>
<div class="subMainSlates" onmouseenter="flip(this)" onmouseleave="flipBack(this)">
    <div class="front">
        <i class="typcn typcn-location-arrow"></i>
        <h3>XPT Logistics</h3>
        <p>The top Company in terms of Export Logistics in Nigeria</p>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        Want to work
    </div>
</div>
```